# jquery can't decode json with c-cedilla

Tags: jquery, json, character, response

jQuery is failing to parse what appears to be a valid json response that includes the french C-cedilla character.

The jQuery json request is this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "retrieve",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (x) { },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { });
```

Sever sends this response:

```
{
    "trist":"{\"Lines\":[{\"C\":\"Director: Beça\"}]}"
}
```

jQuery fails, complaining about invalid character because of the c-cedilla in Beça. Comes back fine if I just inspect the raw json response in the browser. All my investigation so far suggests this should just work, so I have no idea how to take it any further.

Upon further review... the value of the "trist" field is itself json object; in other words, the value of "trist" is intended to extracted as a string, and then later parsed into a Lines object. Perhaps that inner json not properly utf-8 encoded? Perhaps that inner json needs to be 'escaped' in some way.

Comment: did u try it with different outputs without any weird character?

Comment: I'm not sure about those escaped quotes. This would be a valid JSON string response if you use a charset like UTF-8: `'{"trist":{"Lines":[{"C":"Director: Beça"}]}}'`

Comment: Ah, so I must 'unescape what I have escaped' to paraphrase star wars. I'm trying to work out how to do that now. Seems like I might have to write the json manually instead of using jsonWriter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was encoding mismatches on the webpage. Once I set the server to respond with UTF-8 and set the web page charset header to UTF-8, it all worked properly. Thanks to anyone who looked at this including devnull69 whose comment got me re-engaged.